# batch renaming all files in a folder to lowercase letters regex not working

Tags: command-line, bash, regex

I need to rename all folders and files to lowercase, I looked on this forum and found the following command

```
find . -name * -type f -exec rename 'y/A-Z/a-z/' '{}' \;
```

I tried this, and while the command runs fine with no error message, some files are still uppercase.

I also found this online

```
find ./ -depth -exec rename 's/(.)/([/])/$1/\L$2/' {} \;
```

Oddly enough, this worked for one of my folders but not the other one. I'm a linux noob, does anyone know what is going on? I appreciate your time.

Comment: Where exactly did you find the first command? The unquoted `*` in `-name *` would be expanded by the shell - which is almost never what you want - in most cases it would error out (because it would expand to multiple matches); if there is exactly one directory in `.` it would cause `find` to only match files whose names are exactly the same as the directory name.

Comment: I'm just trying every command I find. I found the first one from a mod forum for linux gaming. 
I've tried the command in the other answer, what do I put for the path? My folder is named "sship" and I've put /sship but it says not found

Comment: `/sship` is an absolute path while `sship` is relative. `/sship` means your folder resides in root directory (`/`), which I don't think is the case. You can either use full path like `/home/ubuntu/Desktop/sship` or navigate to the folder which contains `sship` (let's say Desktop) and use `sship`, without any forward slash.